# How do I number duplicate lines sequentially?

Tags: bash, awk, rename

I would like to number duplicate rows sequentially. Possibly using awk, but any unix code will do. For example I would like

```
3J8934
4Y9384
3T2938
3J8934
4Y9384
7I5938
```

to become

```
3J8934_01
4Y9384_01
3T2938_01
3J8934_02
4Y9384_02
7I5938_01
```

So far I have been able to use awk to mark the duplicates with `_02`, but it does not mark the first one or not duplicates with `_01`.

```
awk 'cnt[$0]++{$0=$0"_0"cnt[$0]}1' filename.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You were pretty close. Here's how I would do it:

```
$ awk '{ $0 = $0 sprintf("_%02d", ++count[$0]) } 1' infile
3J8934_01
4Y9384_01
3T2938_01
3J8934_02
4Y9384_02
7I5938_01
```

For each line, we append `sprintf("_%02d", ++count[$0])`, i.e., and underscore followed by a number, zero padded to two digits if applicable. The value of the number is `++count[$0]`: this is the number of times we have seen the line already.

`count` is an associative array indexed by the whole line; is it *pre-incremented* by the `++`, i.e., first incremented, then printed. When we see a line for the first time, the counter is implicitly initialized to zero, incremented, and we append `_01`, and so on.

The `1` at the end is shorthand for `{ print $0 }`, as that is the default action for any true condition.

Comment: @dood Added an explanation.